# Passing a variable to javascript through HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have 3 hidden buttons in my HTML that i have created to hold my values.

A fourth submit button will take the values  of these 3 buttons and use them as parameters for a Javascript function.

**My hidden buttons**

```
<button type="button" value="Title Retrieved should be here" id="TitleHolder" style="visibility: hidden;"></button>
<button type="button" value="Each year, thousands of patients and families from across the United States and beyond travel to Boston Children's Hospital to seek treatment for complex diseases and conditions. All of our patients are unique, but their stories tend to have a lot in common: a serious health problem, doctors and nurses collaborating from half a world away, the remarkable determination of children and families -- and a happy ending." id="StoryHolder" style="visibility: hidden;"></button>
<button type="button" value="25" id="IDHolder" style="visibility: hidden;"></button>
```

**The button to be clicked and to send the values**

```
<a id="btn" class="initialism basic_open" onclick="viewModal(document.getElementById('TitleHolder').value, document.getElementById('StoryHolder').value, document.getElementById('IDHolder').value)" >Read full story &raquo</a> </div>
```

**My javascript function**

```
function viewModal(Title1, Story, ID) {
    var modal = document.getElementById(ID);

    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: thats not clean HTML, looks like some template language. Could you explain?

Comment: You want hidden input's. While a button could hold a value, it makes more since to use hidden inputs.

Comment: sorry i will edit my question and put the client side HTML

Comment: I just edited it, is it clear now?

Comment: Once give an alert in the javascript function to check whether values are coming or not.Everything seems fine in HTML.

Comment: @Alekhya Really? Alert? Please don't and just use `console.log()`

Comment: @Alekhya oh I just tried and it gave me an alert. very weird why it can't proceed with what i'm saying or even read the variable I sent

Comment: @rottenoats thanks I just changed it to inputs! but still not working

Comment: No errors but in the console I put document.write(ID); and it gave me an error saying ID is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code, was the `ID` variable in your `viewModal`.
As you can see here, you never passed your **modal ID** when you called `viewModal`:

```
viewModal(document.getElementById('TitleHolder').value, document.getElementById('StoryHolder').value, document.getElementById('IDHolder').value)
```

I changed your code, to make it "cleaner". Here is a working version of what you want. Avoid adding events directly onto HTML elements.

```js
//Wait till the page has finished loading.
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  
  //Retrieve and store the hidden inputs elements.
  var storyHolder = document.getElementById('StoryHolder');
  var idHolder = document.getElementById('IDHolder');
  var titleHolder = document.getElementById('TitleHolder');

  //Add click event on button.
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
      //When button is clicked, log all the hidden input values.
      console.log(storyHolder.value, idHolder.value, titleHolder.value);

     //TODO: Modal code here.
     //UNCOMMENT: document.getElementById('REPLACE_THIS_WITH_MODAL_ID').style.display = "block";
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="Title Retrieved should be here" id="TitleHolder"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Each year, thousands of patients and families from across the United States and beyond travel to Boston Children's Hospital to seek treatment for complex diseases and conditions. All of our patients are unique, but their stories tend to have a lot in common: a serious health problem, doctors and nurses collaborating from half a world away, the remarkable determination of children and families -- and a happy ending." id="StoryHolder"/>
<input type="hidden" value="25" id="IDHolder">

<a id="btn">Read full story &raquo</a>
```